# How to consume a Web Service running on IIS using ANSI C?

Tags: c, web-services, iis

Is it possible to consume a SOAP or REST web service running on IIS from ANSI C? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gsoap?
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html